# select in select inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00911

I try to make an inner join on select. My select statement is like below

```
SELECT con.fpd_no, 
       con.contract_no, 
        cm.cust_name, 
       (select cm.cust_name, TRIM(cm.address) || ', ' ||  TRIM(cm.zipcode) || ', ' || TRIM(klm.kelurahan_desc) || ', ' || TRIM(kcm.kecamatan_desc) || ', ' || TRIM(kbm.kabupaten_desc) || ', ' || TRIM(prm.propinsi_desc)
        from customer_master cm
        inner join kelurahan_master klm on klm.kelurahan_id=cm.kelurahan_id
        inner join kecamatan_master kcm on kcm.kecamatan_id=klm.kecamatan_id
        inner join kabupaten_master kbm on kbm.kabupaten_id=kcm.kabupaten_id
        inner join propinsi_master prm on prm.propinsi_id=kbm.propinsi_id;) as address, 
        con.principal_amount
   FROM contract con
   JOIN customer_master cm ON cm.cust_no = con.cust_no
   WHERE con.deal_code = 'A005'
    AND con.fpd_date BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '31-01-2016'
    AND con.fpd_no = '0103006116'
    AND con.objt_group = 'MOTOR';
```

but I get this error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character.

Comment: how do you expect SQL to make the link between your "address" field and the table ?  Why don't you make the joins with your master table in the latter request and compute the address column based on the tables in your main select, like regular SQL syntax?

Comment: `...prm.propinsi_id=kbm.propinsi_id;)...` - what's that semi-colon doing there? Remove it; it has no place except right at the end of the sql statement. Also, `con.fpd_date BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '31-01-2016'`: don't rely on implicit date conversions (assuming con.fpd_date is of DATE datatype) - instead, convert the strings to dates, either using the DATE literal (e.g. `DATE 2016-01-01`) or by `to_date()` (e.g. `to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`). If con.fpd_date contains times other than midnight, you're going to exclude data that's after midnight on 31st Jan 2016. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try this:

**remove semicolon on subselect and sure about select returns only one row**

```
SELECT con.fpd_no, con.contract_no, cm.cust_name, (select distinct cm.cust_name, TRIM(cm.address) || ', ' ||  TRIM(cm.zipcode) || ', ' || TRIM(klm.kelurahan_desc) || ', ' || TRIM(kcm.kecamatan_desc) || ', ' || TRIM(kbm.kabupaten_desc) || ', ' || TRIM(prm.propinsi_desc)
from customer_master cm
inner join kelurahan_master klm on klm.kelurahan_id=cm.kelurahan_id
inner join kecamatan_master kcm on kcm.kecamatan_id=klm.kecamatan_id
inner join kabupaten_master kbm on kbm.kabupaten_id=kcm.kabupaten_id
inner join propinsi_master prm on prm.propinsi_id=kbm.propinsi_id) as address, con.principal_amount
   FROM contract con
   JOIN customer_master cm ON cm.cust_no = con.cust_no
   WHERE con.deal_code = 'A005'
    AND con.fpd_date BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '31-01-2016'
    AND con.fpd_no = '0103006116'
    AND con.objt_group = 'MOTOR';
```